# Не работает timeout в discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

В одном боте готовая команда, и она работает. А когда попытался написать её для второго бота, выводит ошибку:

```
Command raised an exception: TypeError: timeout() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'until'
```

Вот сама команда:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['mute', 'мут', 'мьют', 'timemute'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def timeout(ctx, member: discord.Member, time=None, *, reason=None):
    author = ctx.author
    if member != None:
        if time != None:
            t = humanfriendly.parse_timespan(time)
            await member.timeout(until = discord.utils.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=t), reason=reason)
            if reason != None:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = 'Mute ✅',
                    description = f'**{member.mention}**  успешно  замучен  на  **{time}**\n\n**Причина: `{reason}`**',
                    colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 189, 0)
                )        
                await ctx.send(embed=embed) #await ctx.send (f'**{member.mention}** был замучен на **{time}** по причине **"{reason}"**')
            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = 'Mute ✅',
                    description = f'**{member.mention}**  успешно  замучен  на  **{time}**',
                    colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 189, 0)
                )        
                await ctx.send(embed=embed) #await ctx.send (f'**{member.mention}** был замучен на **{time}**')
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title = 'Mute ❌',
                description = f'{author.mention}  укажите  время  наказания',
                colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(171, 0, 0)
            )        
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Mute ❌',
            description = f'{author.mention}  укажите  кого  нужно  наказать',
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(171, 0, 0)
        )        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

В чём проблема, и как её исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё не делал timeout'ов, но я протестировал ваш код и исправил его убрав значение until:

```
await member.timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=t), reason=reason)
```

Так код полностью работает и мутит пользователя.

[image: Тестирование.]

Полный код:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['mute', 'мут', 'мьют', 'timemute'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def timeout(ctx, member: discord.Member, time=None, *, reason=None):
    author = ctx.author
    if member != None:
        if time != None:
            t = humanfriendly.parse_timespan(time)
            await member.timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=t), reason=reason)
            if reason != None:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = 'Mute ✅',
                    description = f'**{member.mention}**  успешно  замучен  на  **{time}**\n\n**Причина: `{reason}`**',
                    colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 189, 0)
                )        
                await ctx.send(embed=embed) #await ctx.send (f'**{member.mention}** был замучен на **{time}** по причине **"{reason}"**')
            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = 'Mute ✅',
                    description = f'**{member.mention}**  успешно  замучен  на  **{time}**',
                    colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 189, 0)
                )        
                await ctx.send(embed=embed) #await ctx.send (f'**{member.mention}** был замучен на **{time}**')
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title = 'Mute ❌',
                description = f'{author.mention}  укажите  время  наказания',
                colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(171, 0, 0)
            )        
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Mute ❌',
            description = f'{author.mention}  укажите  кого  нужно  наказать',
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(171, 0, 0)
        )        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Я уже разобрался, я кажется забыл дать боту нужные права на сервере) Ну и ваше решение тоже помогло. Спасибо!

Comment: Это вызывало бы другую ошибку: MissingPermissions

Comment: Сначала применил ваши поправки, а потом заметил MissingPermissions